# Is this normal? CPU temperature at under 60C but fans running extremely high?

Tags: cpu, macbook, fan, macbook-pro, temperature

I'm running Bootcamp on a MacBook Pro16" with the highest-end CPU/GPU, and I'm finding it runs the fans up a lot; maybe it's also running extremely hot, but under 60C doesn't sound too bad.

[image: screenshot]

This occurs while web browsing, or watching YouTube, while connected to a couple of external displays, which is something Windows machines handle quite well.  The MacBook Pro also seems to get hot very quickly and takes a long time to cool down ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJT660pUOMc&feature=youtu.be)).

I've tried using MacsFanControl to keep the fans down, but then I started hitting thermal throttling when the CPU was hovering around 70C, eventually dropping to 790MHz, which again doesn't feel like it should be the case.

It seems to happen a lot more when connected to external monitors, leading me to believe there is something wrong with the graphics cooling. Apple support seems to think it's not a software issue, but I dread sending it to them and having them claim it's behaving as expected without testing it properly by connecting it to external displays.

Is this normal, or should I push harder and get it fixed?

Comment: Just an FYI, you can't compare performance on a BSD (like MacOS) or Linux OS to Windows... they're two completely different things with little in common _(from how the kernels are structured to something as simple as the network stack or drivers)_, including performance between the two

Comment: I'm assuming this issue doesn't occur in macOS?

Comment: It does as per the video I had uploaded: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJT660pUOMc&feature=youtu.be Same basic issue, under 60 degrees celsius but fans are running at max.

Comment: 2016-2019 Macbook Pros (especially with discrete GPU) are notorious for excessive heat production and too little cooling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your fans. If fans gets dusty they might run faster because they cant cool down the CPU on a normal RPM.

Answer (score 0):

Having a higher end CPU/GPU does not increase the maximum thermals the cooling solution can have.  In fact it only increases how much cooling is required.  Most laptops only have about 65-85 Watts TDP of cooling compared to a desktop which can often have 300-600 Watts TDP of cooling capability.  Being a 16 inch notebook, not a 24 inch, it would be in the 70-75 Watt TDP range.

In all honesty 60 degrees actually sounds about right.  Even desktop processors run around that temperature.  Intel CPUs are known to run hot, especially in macs. The same goes for nVidia GPUs which Apple uses.  Laptops in particular run very hot as well.

As of fan noise, sadly that model laptop has a noisy fan.  You can reduce the fan noise by cleaning the fans.  It might also improve airflow.

Additionally, there are some other things you can do.

First, insure power-scaling is properly enabled.  You should have the lowest setting to the lowest it will go while maintaining the maximum top bracket settings.  This will properly enable the power save behavior to reduce wasted power and heat.

You should never use so-called "performance" mode on your laptop, or anything except benchmarks for that matter.  The mode is a holdover from back when processors took a long time to power up after sleep mode.

Second, if you are only cloning a display across several monitors, use a Display Port signal cloning device instead of a multi-port adapter.  This will prevent the GPU from having to make extra copies of the screen data.

Finally, depending on what browser you use you may have some option to reduce CPU and memory usage.  Chrome and Firefox have such options, Edge, Opera and Safari do not.

Comment: doesn't quit eadd up why th efans are on maximum at only 60 degrees though.